# how to check if a symmetric block matrix is positive difinite

Tags: matrices

I have a question concerning block matrices. Consider a block matrix 
$$ M = \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      A&B\\
      B'& C
    \end{array}
\right], $$
where
$$ C =\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&x\\
      x& 1
    \end{array}
\right] $$
and A is symmetric positive definite. The problem is: find the smallest $x \in (0, 1)$ for which $M$ is positive definite given $A$ and $B$. Is there a smart way to do that that doesn't involve computing determinant of M? I know that $|M|$ may be expressed as $|A - BCB'||C|$, which simplifies the problem slightly, but perhaps there is another way?

Comment: If $B$ is given, then $B'$ is assumed to be the transpose of $B$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, @Marko